# Preventing systemd start conditionally based on configuration

Tags: systemd

I've been struggling with this for the last hours, and as far as I understand the documents, there isn't nearly any straight way around it.
I have a configuration / state called *IS_PAIRED*, which is stored inside some .conf file. If this configuration is set to false, I want to prevent the service from starting, as well as running it's preliminary steps.

Further context: The main service is a long running service. It is part of a bigger overall application. This service needs to run only after the main application has been paired with a different application. The IS_PAIRED configuration is controlled by another service in the same application. It's impossible to say when it will be set - it is the user's choice. All other services in the application can only be started after IS_PAIRED is set. Otherwise, there is no point in starting them. The IS_PAIRED param is persisted. After it is set, the service needs to load on boot.

I have started with this:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/bin/grep -q '^IS_PAIRED=true$' /etc/p.conf
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "echo 'aaa' > /vagrant/b.sh"
ExecStart=/vagrant/a.sh
ExecStopPost=/vagrant/utils/bin/delay_service_restart.sh test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What happens when *IS_PAIRED* isn't true, is that the systemd fails, runs the PostStop, and then keeps on restarting. I don't want this to happen. If this configuration isn't set, the service should just go inactive.
I don't want to switch the *Restart* value to *on-abort*, because sometimes the long-running process (redubbed as *a.sh* here) will catch an exception and close with an error rather than be killed by a signal.

Next, I tried this (the service is named *test*):

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "grep -q '^IS_PAIRED=true$' /etc/p.conf || systemctl stop test"
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "echo 'aaa' > /vagrant/b.sh"
ExecStart=/vagrant/a.sh
ExecStopPost=/vagrant/utils/bin/delay_service_restart.sh test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What happens now is that the second *ExecStartPre* is executed before the service is stopped. This is not good for me, as in the real code there are initializations there I do not want to permit with the configuration not set.

On my last attempt, it really gets weird:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "grep -q '^IS_PAIRED=true$' /etc/p.conf || { systemctl stop test; /bin/false; }"
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "echo 'aaa' > /vagrant/b.sh"
ExecStart=/vagrant/a.sh
ExecStopPost=/vagrant/utils/bin/delay_service_restart.sh test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I thought I'm being tricky here, but no, the second *ExecStartPre* still ran.
I thought I'm going crazy, so I verified that the first one does evaluate to an error:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ sudo /bin/bash -c "grep -q '^IS_PAIRED=true$' /etc/p.conf || { systemctl stop test; /bin/false; }"
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ sudo echo $?
1
```

So overall, I'm pretty lost, and I have two questions:

1. How am I supposed to achieve the logic I want? I can see two
   possible solutions I don't like:

   - Making the configuration check a service. This is wrong. There is nothing service-like about it.
   - Creating a wrapper runner where the check is the first thing that happens. Well, I am currently migrating a logically organized upstart into this systemd. In the upstart this check is in the pre-start, and rightly so. It belongs this logically. Otherwise I have to start creating separate wrappers for each type of service - some of them are in java, some of them in C++, some have additional pre-start actions, and all have this precondition.
   - Having the software that sets *IS_PAIRED* in *p.conf* create a file, and then use the *ConditionPathExists* directive. This is the only one I am willing to consider, but it really is quite horrible.
2. In case there is no right way - why isn't my last hack working? :(

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context in which these services run and/or are expected to run? Right now the description of your services is extremely vague, which makes it impossible to think of any possible alternatives.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, The main service is a long running service. It is part of a bigger overall application. This service needs to run only after the main application has been paired with a different application. The IS_PAIRED configuration is controlled by another service in the same application. It's impossible to say when it will be set - it is the user's choice. All other services in the application can only be started after IS_PAIRED is set. Otherwise, there is no point in starting them. The IS_PAIRED param is persisted. After it is set, the service needs to load on boot.

Comment: But what does it mean to be "paired"? Surely the "IS_PAIRED" directive in p.conf is not the only change that this "pairing" accomplishes. For instance, two applications might communicate via a UNIX domain socket, which doesn't exist until a setup is completed. Finally, is it worth bothering with this at all? If the service hasn't been paired, why shouldn't it fail when someone tries to start it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, simplistically, this pairing is two-way SSL trust generation, following which two servers can freely communicate over HTTPS (no socket).
My problem with the service failing at this state is that it would attempt to restart, litter the syslog and cause non-trivial _ExecStopPost_ to run. I can't use any other value for _Restart_ because the main process can be either killed or exit with an error.

Comment: Well, in that case, the file containing the certificate would exist only if the pairing had taken place, yes?

Comment: That indeed is another hacky way to go around it. What I don't like about it is that the certificate file is an inner implementation detail that can change, while the _IS_PAIRED_ configuration is a standard high-level logical abstraction in the software.
I am receiving the feeling that what I want can't be achieved straight-forwardly, which is a shame, because a directive such as ConditionCommandSucceeds sounds very useful.
After thinking about it today I am leaning towards making a wrapper service which checks the configuration and my services depend on it finishing successfully. Overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`ExecCondition=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=) can help?

```
[Service]
ExecCondition=/usr/bin/myapp-exec-condition
```

The application will only start if `myapp-exec-condition` exits with status 0.